# C# How would I go about connecting multiple clients to the same server?

Tags: c#, .net, server, client

I'm working on a client server end and am not too familiar with .net and C#, was wondering how I would go about connecting multiple clients to the same server. Would prefer to keep using TcpClient if I can.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
    using System.Threading;

  namespace TFServerClient
   {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      private TcpClient client;
      public StreamReader STR;
      public StreamWriter STW;
      public string receive;
      public String text_to_send;
      TcpListener listener;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IPAddress[] localIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()); //gets my IP
        foreach(IPAddress address in localIP)
        {
            if(address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                txtIPServer.Text = address.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListenBackground.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void ReceiveData_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while(client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                receive = STR.ReadLine();
                this.txtChat.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { txtChat.AppendText("You: " + receive + "\n"); }));
                receive = "";
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void SendData_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if(client.Connected)
        {
            STW.WriteLine(text_to_send);
            this.txtChat.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { txtChat.AppendText("Me: " + text_to_send + "\n"); }));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Send failed");
        }
        SendData.CancelAsync();
    }

    private async void ListenBackground_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtChat.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { txtChat.AppendText("Awaiting Connection...\n"); }));
        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        this.txtChat.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { txtChat.AppendText("Client Connected.\n"); }));
        STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        STW.AutoFlush = true;

        ReceiveData.RunWorkerAsync(); //Start recieving data in background
        SendData.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; //able to cancel thread
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        IPEndPoint IP_End = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtIPClient.Text), int.Parse(txtPortClient.Text));

        try {
            client.Connect(IP_End);
            if(client.Connected)
            {
                txtChat.AppendText("Connected To Server " + "\n");
                STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                STW.AutoFlush = true;

                ReceiveData.RunWorkerAsync(); //Start recieving data in background
                SendData.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; //able to cancel thread
            }
        } catch(Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtMessage.Text != "")
        {
            text_to_send = txtMessage.Text;
            SendData.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtMessage.Text = "";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you have posted code and explained what you are working on however you have not stated in regards to the current code, what the Issue is.. please edit the question and state what the existing issue you are experiencing with the current code. `This is not a Code Factory Service` site..!

Comment: If you open your app twice and connect them then you have multiple connected clients... is that what you meant?

Comment: Current code only allows one client to connect then stops. I need to figure out how to have multiple clients connected to the chat server. Which I can't figure out how to do. Opening up multiple doesn't work because my code is only listening for one.

Comment: Consider programming the network API - OUTSIDE of whatever UI you use. The code is needlessly concoluted with callback methods that make little sense for a server - which should use System.NET OR a higher level API (web api self hosted for example).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply need to multi-thread your server-side code, similar to the following:

```
listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, portNumber);
listener.Start();

while (true)
{
    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => SOME ACTION));
}
```

The delegate you pass into the ThreadStart constructor will handle creating your stream reader and stream writer. It should also carry out any server-side business logic you want to execute.

The AcceptTcpClient method is a blocking method, so a new Thread instance will only be created every time there is a TCP request received from a client.

Examples of this kind of action can be found:

[Here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm) at csharp.net-informations.com

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=137979) at codeproject.com

**Warning:** By viewing downloads associated with the article at codeproject.com you agree to the Terms of Service and the article's licence. The licence is The Code Project Open License (CPOL)

Answer (score -1):

There is a really nice free lib called NetSockets which you can use for that.
( https://netsockets.codeplex.com/ ) < For Downloading the lib.

The lib is TCP and multi-threaded , here is how to use it:

- Server Side:

Creating the server :

```
static NetObjectServer server = new NetObjectServer();
```

Starting the server:

```
server.Start(IPAddress.Any, 7482);
```

Event Handlers:

```
server.OnClientAccepted += server_OnClientAccepted;

server.OnClientConnected += server_OnClientConnected;

server.OnClientDisconnected += server_OnClientDisconnected;

server.OnClientRejected += server_OnClientRejected;

server.OnReceived += server_OnReceived;

server.OnStarted += server_OnStarted;

server.OnStopped += server_OnStopped;
```

- Client Side:

Creating the client:

```
static readonly NetObjectClient client = new NetObjectClient();
```

Event Handlers:

```
client.OnConnected += client_OnConnected;

client.OnDisconnected += client_OnDisconnected;

client.OnReceived += client_OnReceived;
```

Connecting:

```
client.TryConnect("127.0.0.1",7482);
```

This info was taken from Joseph Bisaillon's blog ( http://www.josephbisaillon.com/ )

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12233498)

Comment: Thank you for the review i fixed it! :)

Comment: Actually no. You still offer a needless third party library to do what can be done with standard .net resources.